# Migrate Docker Engine nodes from dockershim to cri-dockerd

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I'm having EKS cluster V1.24 in that CONTAINER-RUNTIME=containerd://1.6.6 due to that I m not able to use Docker Build I have gone through a few Docs and found out that if I change my CONTAINER-RUNTIME-ENDPOINT to unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock and CONTAINER-RUNTIME Remote according to docs then I can able to use docker cmd there will be some change instead of "docker build" cmd will be "crictl build" and we will be able to use all docker cmd [image]

I follow this doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/migrate-dockershim-dockerd/ and this doc https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/kubernetes-v1.24-how-to-migrate-away-from-dockershim/ this all docs have Cluster deploy locally using KUBEADM and I m having EKS Cluster v1.24
so I find out that I have to create Customizing managed nodes with launch templates I follow this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html#containerd-bootstrap after applying ClusterConfig.yaml file nodegroup started creating but it is get stuck with creating status and getting failed after some time i don't now why my node group is not creating